# How to add subview on custom TitleView's subview

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I set custom view to titleView of UINavigationBar.
When I just set the view with frame, it works fine.

However if I add any subview to a view that I set to a title view, it just does not appear.

**A view added to titleView**

```
class NavigationBarSearchBar: UIView {

    let view: UIView = {
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupSubviews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    private func setupSubviews() {

        addSubview( view )
        [
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
        view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor)
        ].forEach { $0.isActive = true }
    }
}
```

**Declaration on View Controller**

```
private lazy var searchBar: UIView = {
        let sb = NavigationBarSearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: 40))
        return sb
    }()
```

**Set the custom view to nav bar**

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

Comment: You need text in titleView or searchBar ?? BTW for search bar  use -> [search-bar-in-navigation-bar-title](https://riptutorial.com/ios/example/9505/search-bar-in-navigation-bar-title)

Comment: I'm able to successfully embed search bar to UINavigationBar however doing this has some problem to me.  cancel button is set to disabled only when search bar is having focus. I need the cancel button to be enabled all the time. If I could replicate it easily, I would be better to handle all possible event might make cancel button disabled(and are quite many).

Comment: Can you please update your question and mention where you facing issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
lazy   var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))
searchBar.sizeToFit()
navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a view with Frame and add to navigationItem**

```
var viewTitle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 30))
viewTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
navigationItem?.titleView = viewTitle
```